Nginx server doesn't load static css files
I'm trying to deploy my django site to ubuntu server nginx by following this tutorial (https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu).
Deployment works, but css not working. I figured it's something with collectstatic but not sure. Funny enough css worked properly for 0.0.0.0:8000 port.
This is from settings.py
STATIC_URL = 'static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
]

I noticed in tutorial that they don't have STATICFILES_DIRS... and... STATIC_URL and STATIC_ROOT are same 'static'. Could this be an issue...?
also, tried editing path to static with sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/django_project
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name xxx.xx.xx.xxx; #my ip, just hide it for purpose of question

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    location /static/ {
        alias /home/muser/django_project/static/;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
    }
}

Any idea what I did wrong? Thanks in advance!

i saw the problem in you nginx configuration on static location block there you have provided the path for the static folder
location /static/ {
        alias /home/muser/django_project/static/;
}

in the location you give path to static folder which you should change the path to staticfiles
location /static/ {
        alias /home/muser/django_project/staticfiles/;
}

because you had given the name for the static_root folder is staticfiles
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')

and don't forget to run this command to create a staticfiles folder.
python manage.py collectstatic

I hope this will solve your problem.
